# Git: Creating branch out another branch showing on main level

Tags: git, github, git-branch, git-branch-sculpting

I have created a new branch out another branch:

master
   ---develpment
         ---------FeatureA

But if I check the branch structure it shows FeatureA branch at the same level as develpment:

```
 git branch -a
  development
* FeatureA
  master
  remotes/origin/development
  remotes/origin/FeatureA
  remotes/origin/master
```

My question to guys is guy FeatureA is not showing as sub-branch of development?

I'll really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no such thing as a "subbranch". All branches are equal. But you can use different tools to view relations between branches. Try

```
git show-branch
git log --all --decorate --graph
gitk --all
```

Answer (score 1):

In git, branches are just pointers to commits. After a branch is created, it does not remember from which branch it was created (in fact, a new branch is not necessarily created from any other branch, it can be created from any arbitrary commit) and has no relation to other branches.

See [corresponding chapter](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Branching-Branches-in-a-Nutshell) in a git book.

There are [various GUIs](https://git-scm.com/downloads/guis/) that can help you visualize the repository tree and relation between commits and branches.